# what's difference between rosmake & makefile?

Tags: ros, makefile, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I didn't change any source file and run rosmake twice,
I found that rosmake will also remake again.
In this case it takes 2.66 sec,but in other it may cause longer.
What's happened?

here is the log:

[rosmake-1] Starting >>> robot_setup_tf [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< robot_setup_tf [PASS] [ 2.66 seconds ]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10480/what%27s-difference-between-rosmake-&-makefile?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let me see if I understand what you're asking: Why does ROS remake unchanged code when you perform two rosmakes in sequence?

The short answer-- it just does. rosmake acts the same as make, with some extras. It cycles through all your package's dependencies (and the package itself) to check if anything has changed.

'rosmake -s' will only build the package you specify, and not its dependencies. 'rosmake --pre-clean' will clean the specified package and all its dependencies before remaking all of them. 'rosmake -s --pre-clean' will clean and remake only the specified package.

---

Originally posted by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) with karma: 753 on 2011-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most likely it didn't actually build anything the second time. It takes a few seconds for it to figure out that it doesn't need to build again. That's probably what you are seeing.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-07-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2